# Create nested dictionary in Python from textfile

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem regarding the nested dictionary in Python3. Have tried many ways but I am still stuck with an unexpected result of the program. The text file contains the following information:

```
SERVER01_X  
--------------------------------------------------
Tue May 07, 01:15 
--------------------------------------------------
MEMORY: ''

Value  Name
876    SWAP_MEMORY
180    BUFFER
1371   TOTAL

--------------------------------------------------
Tue May 07, 01:45 
--------------------------------------------------
MEMORY: ''

Value  Name
871    SWAP_MEMORY
187    BUFFER
1379   TOTAL


SERVER02_Y  
--------------------------------------------------
Tue May 07, 01:15 
--------------------------------------------------
MEMORY: ''

Value  Name
76    SWAP_MEMORY
80    BUFFER
371   TOTAL

--------------------------------------------------
Tue May 07, 01:45 
--------------------------------------------------
MEMORY: ''

Value  Name
71    SWAP_MEMORY
87    BUFFER
379   TOTAL
```

the expected output that needs to be produced by the program as below:

```
server_information = {
     SERVER01: {
                 Tue May 07, 01:15 : {MEMORY: {SWAP_MEMORY: 876, BUFFER: 180, TOTAL: 1371}} 
                 Tue May 07, 01:45 : {MEMORY: {SWAP_MEMORY: 871, BUFFER: 180, TOTAL: 1379}}                 
                }      
     SERVER02 : {
                 Tue May 07, 01:15 : {MEMORY: {SWAP_MEMORY: 76, BUFFER: 80, TOTAL: 371}} 
                 Tue May 07, 01:45 : {MEMORY: {SWAP_MEMORY: 71, BUFFER: 87, TOTAL: 379}}                 
                }      
}
```

Following is the program that I have tried:

```py
 #!/usr/bin/python3

import re

def convert_tuple(tuple):
    string = ' '.join(tuple)
    return string

with open('file3.txt') as infile:
    answer = {}  # dictionary initialisation
    for line in infile:
        server_name = ''.join(re.findall(r'^(\w+)\_\w{1}',line))
        # Tue May 07, 01:15
        dates = re.findall(r'^\w{3}\s+(\w{3})\s+(\d{2})\,\s+(\d{2}\:\d{2}).*',line)
        object_types = re.findall(r'(^\w+)\:.*',line)

        object_type_values = re.findall(r'^(\d+)\s+(\w+)',line)
        if server_name:
            key = server_name 
        for date in dates:
            date_converted = (convert_tuple(date))
        for object_type in object_types:
            obj_type = object_type
        for object_type_value, object_type_name in object_type_values:
            answer[key] = {date_converted: {obj_type: {object_type_name: {object_type_value}}}}
            print(answer)
```

The output of my program as below:

```
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:15': {'MEMORY': {'SWAP_MEMORY': {'876'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:15': {'MEMORY': {'BUFFER': {'180'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:15': {'MEMORY': {'TOTAL': {'1371'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'SWAP_MEMORY': {'871'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'BUFFER': {'187'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'TOTAL': {'1379'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'TOTAL': {'1379'}}}}, 'SERVER02': {'May 07 01:15': {'MEMORY': {'SWAP_MEMORY': {'76'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'TOTAL': {'1379'}}}}, 'SERVER02': {'May 07 01:15': {'MEMORY': {'BUFFER': {'80'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'TOTAL': {'1379'}}}}, 'SERVER02': {'May 07 01:15': {'MEMORY': {'TOTAL': {'371'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'TOTAL': {'1379'}}}}, 'SERVER02': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'SWAP_MEMORY': {'71'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'TOTAL': {'1379'}}}}, 'SERVER02': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'BUFFER': {'87'}}}}}
{'SERVER01': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'TOTAL': {'1379'}}}}, 'SERVER02': {'May 07 01:45': {'MEMORY': {'TOTAL': {'379'}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the prettiest answer but it does work.

I have not touched any of the regex expressions but I have added a section that checks whether there are values in the dictionary already. Depending whether there were values and keys, I can add the values that are relevant.

```py
import re


def convert_tuple(tuple):
    string = ' '.join(tuple)
    return string


with open('file3.txt') as infile:
    answer = {}  # dictionary initialisation
    for line in infile:
        server_name = ''.join(re.findall(r'^(\w+)\_\w{1}', line))
        # Tue May 07, 01:15
        dates = re.findall(r'^\w{3}\s+(\w{3})\s+(\d{2})\,\s+(\d{2}\:\d{2}).*', line)
        object_types = re.findall(r'(^\w+)\:.*', line)

        object_type_values = re.findall(r'^(\d+)\s+(\w+)', line)
        if server_name:
            key = server_name
        for date in dates:
            date_converted = (convert_tuple(date))
        for object_type in object_types:
            obj_type = object_type
        for object_type_value, object_type_name in object_type_values:
            if answer.get(key):
                if answer[key].get(date_converted):
                    if answer[key][date_converted].get(obj_type):
                        if not answer[key][date_converted][obj_type].get(object_type_name):
                            answer[key][date_converted][obj_type][object_type_name] = object_type_value
                    else:
                        answer[key][date_converted][object_type] = {object_type_name: object_type_value}
                else:
                    answer[key][date_converted] = {obj_type: {object_type_name: object_type_value}}
            else:
                answer[key] = {date_converted: {obj_type: {object_type_name: object_type_value}}}

import json

parsed = json.loads(str(answer).replace("'", '"'))
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4))
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "SERVER01": {
        "May 07 01:15": {
            "MEMORY": {
                "SWAP_MEMORY": "876",
                "BUFFER": "180",
                "TOTAL": "1371"
            }
        },
        "May 07 01:45": {
            "MEMORY": {
                "SWAP_MEMORY": "871",
                "BUFFER": "187",
                "TOTAL": "1379"
            }
        }
    },
    "SERVER02": {
        "May 07 01:15": {
            "MEMORY": {
                "SWAP_MEMORY": "76",
                "BUFFER": "80",
                "TOTAL": "371"
            }
        },
        "May 07 01:45": {
            "MEMORY": {
                "SWAP_MEMORY": "71",
                "BUFFER": "87",
                "TOTAL": "379"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted this neater I'm sure the people over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ wouldn't mind helping you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oliver, it's working fine as expected. Could you help to elaborate for the checking values section?

Comment: At the base layer for example: if there is not a value at the root that is the same as the ```server_name``` variable then it will make a new branch (dictionary) assigned to the key server_name. This is handled by the .get(key) function which returns True or None depending on whether the key is present already. In the case where the key is already assigned it will move up a dictionary and perform the same checks. This avoids the problem of data getting overwritten. This was the problem you were facing as you can see in your traceback the values for dict[server_name] were changing each time.

Comment: Thanks Oliver for your explanation.